# To execute multiple SQL files in single unix shell script

Tags: oracle, unix

I have a SQL file`query.sql` running thorugh a unix shell script and it directs an ouput to another SQL file called as `result.sql`

First file will give the sample output of below which will be written in the result.sql,

```
drop * from table1;
drop * from table 2;
drop * from table 3;  etc..
```

I need to execute both `query.sql` and `result.sql` in a single shell script and this should create a output file called as `output.txt`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something on this idea should work:

```
sqlplus -s username/password@servername << EOF
@query.sql
spool output.txt
@result.sql
spool off
EOF
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your comments. Actually the result.sql is the output of the query.sql. here i need to execute the first query file (query.sql) and to get the output in the second file(result.sql). And this two files needs to be executed in the same shell script file and output of the result.sql to be written in the output.txt file.

Comment: Hi @Ed, My first file query.sql contains the below  CONNECT username/password@SID

whenever SQLERROR EXIT 1;
set linesize 32767
set heading off
set termout off
set trimout on
set pagesize 50000
set trimspool on
set feedback OFF
SET  SQLBLANKLINES ON
--set markup html ON
echo OFF


spool /tmp/chan/result.sql

SELECT CONCAT(CONCAT('select count(*) from ',TABLE_NAME),';') AS QUERYSET
FROM USER_TABLES WHERE   REGEXP_LIKE (LOWER(TABLE_NAME),'^bpjd_job_dependency_(pre|pst)_')
order by TABLE_NAME desc;

spool off;
exit;

Comment: Your `query.sql` seems solid. I've moved the `spool output.txt` in my answer above so it comes just before the `@result.sql`; therefore it will only capture output from when you run `result.sql`. You'll also want to specify your folder when you run it: `@/tmp/chan/result.sql`.